# SearchManager.OnDismissListener never called

Tags: android, dismiss

My goal was to copy the "play music" app search function. From what I can gather, when I press the search button, a new activity is created, and the searchview is automatically expanded. When the arrow or back button, to close the search widget, is pressed, the activity closes. Everything works, besides the onDismiss method not being called. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Search activity is started via an intent, when the search icon is pressed. Below you see the code for creating the search widget in the search activity, which mimics play music as described above.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_option, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchMenuItem.expandActionView();

        searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new SearchManager.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                //Method never called. Logs don't show up/
                Log.i("1234Dismiss", "onDismiss called");
                finish();
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this instead. It works perfectly for me in all my apps.

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

                        // Do what you want to do when the search is collapsed
                        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

                        // Do what you want to do when the search is expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });
```